# padding the middle of a string

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have a Textbox field that takes in a string with a character limit of 10. I would like to implement a short hand version because there are a lot of zeros in the string that have to be entered. so an example of the string is T000028999. but id like to key in T28999 and have the zeros padded between the "T" and the "28999" and show up as the T000028999 string in the Textbox field.
Is this even possible?

I've tried searching examples on google and have only found ways to pad the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: What are the rules?  Is it always on letter in front and numbers at the end?  Any chance it's two letters?

Comment: its just the one letter and the numbers that follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to keep the first character, so you can use `oldString.Chars(0)` to get that.

You want the remainder of the string: `oldString.Substring(1)`, and you can pad it to the width you require with a character of your choice with `PadLeft`, like this:

```
Dim newString = oldString.Chars(0) & oldString.Substring(1).PadLeft(9, "0"c)
```

It would be a good idea to check that `oldString` is at least 1 character long before doing that otherwise the `.Chars(0)` will give an error.

*Alternatively* you could insert a new string of the required quantity of "0"s:

```
Dim newString = oldString.Insert(1, New String("0"c, 10 - oldString.Length))
```

A good place to perform the formatting would be in the control's [Validating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netframework-4.8) event handler. (The TextChanged event handler would not be a good place because it would interfere with the user's typing.)

---

Refs:

- [String.Chars[Int32] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=netframework-4.8)
- [String.Substring Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8)
- [String.PadLeft Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8)
- [String.Insert(Int32, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8)
- [String Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It works if you paste in the short hand string e.g. "T27399" but as soon as you go to type in the textbox field the result is "T000000000" and it doesn't allow you to finish entering the "27399".

Comment: @Rufus7Ls On what event do you want the textbox to add the zeros? I guess you are using the TextChanged event, whereas the [Validating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netframework-4.8) event might be more useful.